# Overflow only certain elements

Tags: html, css

I've got a div with `overflow: hidden`, and a fairly large collection of elements inside it, which I want to be hidden while overflowing their parent. However I've also got two custom dropdowns, which I'd like to overlap and exit the div while open. Is there anyway to avoid the overflow hidden effect for specific elements? Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/akzu4sc0/). Say I want the blue square to go over the red border and overflow it's parent's bounds, but want the green one to remain cut off and hidden.

Comment: This question was asked before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367060/setting-overflowhidden-only-for-certain-elements - have a read, the answer in there is still relevant. Here is the fiddle they used: http://jsfiddle.net/sEX3n/4/

Comment: Not quite, actually. I really do need the html structure to remain pretty much the same, or at least keep the elements that shouldn't be hidden INSIDE the `overflow: hidden` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can overlap/hidden of certain element with pseudo elements see this example.

html

```
<div class="red">
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.red {
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.red:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 70px;
    background: rgb(243, 245, 246);
    bottom: -70px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.blue,.green {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  bottom: -40px;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 40px;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
  z-index: -1;
  right: 40px; 
}
```

here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akzu4sc0/5/)

Comment: Thanks, but moving "blue" out of the `overflow: hidden` element isn't something I can do. It needs to be in there. I was hoping there would be some trick/hack involving z-indices or something.

Comment: That's quite clever :D But yeah, the three boxes example is an oversimplification of what my actual page looks like.

Comment: so you want to move with this solution ?

Comment: I'll accept your answer in a few hours if there's no alternative solution that fits my use case. It's quite possible that it's the best solution at the time.